# Non-existence of a Surjective Function from a Set to Its Subsets (Cantor's theorem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that: Let A be a set and let $P(A)$ be the set of all subsets of $A$. Then there is no surjection $f: A→P(A)$.

Here is what I thought:

if $A=\{a,b\}$ then it has only two elements where $P(A)=\{∅,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ has 4 elements. Therefore $f:A→P(A)$ cannot be surjective. But I have some problems:

1) How is it possible that any $f$ function to take $\{a\}$ from set $A$ to $\{a,b\}$? Maybe because I am thinking mainly about functions with real values like $f(x)=2x$, I find it a little bit strange that a function to take an element of a set to another set which has more elements. Is it possible?

edit: Now I thought that if $f(x)$ is $\sqrt{x}$, then $f(4)=±2$ which means it took an element from a set to a set which has 2 elements. But still I find it kind of strange to denote $f(\{a\})=\{a,b,c,...\}$

2) How can I construct a explicit proof for this question?

Regards

Comment: Saying that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ in your edit is **not** the same as saying that $f(4) = \pm 2$. A function always produces **one** output for any accepted input.

Comment: For those who are looking for an explanation for the answer given by Asaf Karagila, you can find that here: https://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/units/3/textbook/06.php Piece of advice: spend some time understanding the proof by Asaf before clicking this link.

Comment: @adjr2 that link has died. Do you know an active link?

Comment: I found this proof video helpful.It complements with answers given here.Hope it helps..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlKeEzYwtxw

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Cantor's theorem states:

> **Suppose that $A$ is a set and $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ is any function, then $f$ is not surjective.**

The proof is quite simple, and constructive!

*Proof.* Suppose that $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ is a function, we define $D=\{a\in A\mid a\notin f(a)\}$. This is a good definition, since $f(a)$ is a subset of $A$, and $a$ is an element of $A$, we can ask whether or not $a\in f(a)$. So $D$ is the set of those elements of $A$ which do not have this property.

Of course that $D\in\mathcal P(A)$ since it is clearly a subset of $A$. We will show that $f(a)\neq D$ for all $a\in A$.

1. If $a\in D$ then, by definition of $D$, $a\notin f(a)$. So $f(a)\neq D$, since the element $a$ belongs to D but not to $f(a)$.
2. If $a\notin D$ then, by definition of $D$, $a\in f(a)$. By the same argument, again $f(a)\neq D$.

Either way, $D\neq f(a)$ for all $a\in A$. Therefore $f$ is not surjective. $\square$

---

Note that for different functions we have different $D$'s. It is possible that $D=A$ (e.g. if $f(a)=\varnothing$ for all $a$), or it could be $\varnothing$ (e.g. if $f(a)=\{a\}$ for all $a$). However regardless to its value it will not be in the range of $f$.

Comment: How does f(a) is subset of A ,shouldn't it be subset of P(A) ?

Comment: I didnot understand the proof .Can you explain with example ?

Comment: Also does f(a) consists of elements of power set of A ?

Comment: Could you please explain your post with an example? This post, is in its current version, is really difficult for me to comprehend. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry to necro this post, but is P(A) the powerset of A or { Property(A) | a <- A }? I've seen both notations and it's hard for me to be sure in this case, so I'm guessing it might be for others too.

Comment: @BrainFRZ: Power set.

Comment: I'm embarrasses to ask this question; yet here goes. Why can you not use this construction to show there is no surjection between any two sets. Or, maybe a better question, what is it about the set and its power set that makes this work, but that it doesn't work in general. Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew: The best way to do this is to try and work this argument with a surjection, like the identity function from some set to itself, or a constant map into a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

Look up Cantor's Theorem. There are several versions of this theorem. The basic version is to the effect that there is no bijection between a set $A$ and its power set $P(A)$. One of the proofs goes by showing there is no surjection from $A$ to $P(A)$. What one does is to assume there is, so that for each $a$ there is a subset $f(a)$ in the power set. Then one defines a set $B$ by saying that $x$ is in $B$ if and only if $x$ is NOT in the set $f(x)$. Now you ask: Is $x$ in $B$? If it is, it isn't, and if it isn't then it is... either way you get a contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for an explanation for the answer given by Asaf Karagila:

Given a set of any non-zero size, it is possible to create a larger set by taking the set of subsets of the original. 
Suppose we have a set N, consisting of  {A,B,C,D}.  We can then identify set S as the set of all subsets of N. We can conduct a little mental experiment by writing the members of N in a row and then the members of S in another row below the first, like so:

```
N        A    B    C    D
S       {} {A} {B} {A} {D} {AB} {AC} {AD} {BC} {BD} {CD} {ABC} {ABD} {ACD} {BCD} {ABCD}
```

Next, we randomly take four elements of S and match them up with the elements of N. Say we take  {A} {AB} {BD} {ACD} and match them with A B C D of N respectively. 
We can find an element of S that is not matched up checking whether an element of set N is matched with a subset that contains it.  For example, “yes” for A, “no” for B, “no” for  C, and “yes” for  D. With this information, we can be sure that the subset {BC} has not been matched with any member of N. Because every element of N has been matched with an element of S, and there is at least one “leftover” element of S, we can say that S is definitely larger than N.  Note that we did not have to count the members of either set to figure this out.

Let’s again attempt to match up every member of N with a member of D.  We can ask the “yes or no” questions from before to find out which members of N are paired up with subsets that contain them. Let’s say that any members of N for which the answer is “no” go into a new set called W.  The set  W  is then the subset of N containing members that are not paired up with a subset that contains them. Because W is a subset of N, it must be in S, which is the set of all subsets of N. Can W be matched up with some element of N? Let’s say that w, a member of N, is matched up with W. If w  is in W, then it is matched up with a subset that contains it, which by definition means that it cannot be in W; therefore, we have a logical contradiction.

Source: (read section 3.6)
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.learner.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/MathIlluminated_03_txt.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiNyeffwrjoAhUPU30KHTgoCfQQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0HWmjFKYKJ1GsOjko3Fk7f