# Onto mappings from S to the set of all subsets of S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

QUESTION. If $S$ is any set, prove that it is impossible to find a mapping of $S$ onto $S^{\ast}$. ( $S^{\ast}$ is the set of all subsets of $S$). 
MY PROOF:

I ask my proof is right or wrong.....

If $S$ has $n$ element then $S^{\ast}$ has $ 2^n$ elements. it means  $S^{\ast}$ have greater number of elements than $S$
so every member of  $S^{\ast}$ cannot be associated with an member of $S$ , because of pigeon hole principle which says, If $n > m$ pigeons are put into $m$ pigeonholes, there's a hole with more than one pigeon. and if a member of $S$ associate more than one member of $S^{\ast}$ function not defined so for function to be defined some member of $S^{\ast}$ should not be associated with any member of $S$ so function is not onto.

Comment: "if $S$ has $n$ elements, then $S$* has $2^n$ elements" - that's only true (in the sense that you probably intended) if $S$ is finite.

Comment: In other words, you've done the easy part --- the hard part is doing it for infinite sets.

Comment: This is cantor's theorem, which state that there exist no onto function from a set to its power set.....

Comment: @relep The quote you mention is also true if $S$ is infinite (in that case the premisse "$S$ has $n$ elements" is not true). I suspect that's why you added "in the sense that you probably intended". Sorry for my nitpicking ;).

Comment: @drhab I was thinking more along the lines of $n$ being the cardinality of $S$ (though that would be unusual notation indeed) - then $S$* has cardinality $2^n$, but here $2^n$ denotes quite a different thing. But of course your nitpicking is correct as well - luckily I was covered. :)

Comment: See also [Non-existence of a Surjective Function from a Set to Its Subsets (Cantor's theorem)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214807/non-existence-of-a-surjective-function-from-a-set-to-its-subsets-cantors-theor) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/214807).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function f:S$\rightarrow$S*

Let A={x$\in$S|x$\notin$f(x)}$\in$S*.

Now claim that there is no a$\in$S such that f(a)=A,if such element exist then we will get paradox.
suppose there exist a$\in$S such that f(a)=A,we have two possibility either a$\in$f(a) or a$\notin$f(a).Suppose a$\in$f(a)=A,this implies a$\notin$f(a) by construction of A.similarly we get contradiction for the other one.

So function f is not onto.

Comment: give some example

Comment: what do you mean by example? Given any set(finite or infinite) there is no onto map from the set to its power set...Whatever you have proved is ok for finite set...I have just gave general prove...