# Showing a function $f$ cannot be surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Good day all!

So I have a question about the problem:

Let $E$ be a set, and $f$ be a mapping from $E$ to $P(E)$.

Consider a set $A$ such that $x$ is in $E$ but $x$ in NOT in $f(x)$

Show $f$ cannot be surjective.

My question is: How is this?

I see that if $x$ is in $A$ then $x$ is not in $f(x)$ which means $x$ is not in $P(E)$.
How is $x$ in $E$ but $x$ not in $P(E)$?

Is my understanding flawed?

Comment: $x$ is an element of $E$, not a subset of $E$, so in general, you would not expect it to be in $P(E)$, whose elements are subsets of $E$. (There are exceptions, where a set contains some subsets of itself as elements. But in general you would not expect it to happen.)

Comment: ok, so to prove this do I just show that A is not contained in P(E)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\{x\in E,\, x\notin f(x)\}\in P(E)$. So if $f$ is surjective, then there exists $y\in E$ such that $f(y)=A$. Try to show that this leads to a contradiction.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem

Comment: I almost see what you are saying, but how is f(y)=A?

Comment: By definition of surjectivity, _if_ $f$ is surjective, such a $y$ exists.

Comment: So this already shows the contradiction right? Since f(y)=A but A is the set of all elements in E such that y is not an element of f(y)?

Comment: The contradiction comes from the fact that if $y\in A$, then $y\notin f(y)$, by definition of $A$. But $f(y)=A$. So we have $y\in A\implies y\notin A$. Similarly, $y\notin A\implies y\in A$...

Comment: ahh. Ok, thanks. Logically it makes sense. Its just the notation that throws me off since im new to most of it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, this is Cantors Theorem. 
Listed here:

[Non-existence of a Surjective Function from a Set to Its Subsets (Cantor's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214807/non-existence-of-a-surjective-function-from-a-set-to-its-subsets-cantors-theor)

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you ask how $x\in E$ and $x\notin P(E)$ can be true at the same time.

Well, that is easy to see with an example:

Be $E=\{1,2,\}$. Then $P(E)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$.
Clearly in this case none of the elements of $E$ is in $P(E)$. Note that $1\ne\{1\}$.

However note that in other cases, elements of $E$ can be elements of $P(E)$. For example, consider $E=\{\emptyset\}$, then $P(E)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. Here the only element of $E$ ($\emptyset$) is also member of $P(E)$.