# Explaining whether a function is injective/surjection ($f\colon\Bbb N\to P(\Bbb N)$)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $f\colon\Bbb N\to P(\Bbb N)$ be given by $$f(n)=\{n+1,n+2,n+3,\dots\}.$$
>   $(a)$ Is $f$ an **injection**? Explain.
>
> $(b)$ Is $f$ an **surjection**? Explain.

$(a)$

A function is **injective** when $f(x_1) = f(x_2)\implies x_1 = x_2$.

But since this is a sequence, I'm not quite sure. It seems to be injective as each $n\in \Bbb N$ gives you a unique $f(n)$, e.g. $(n = 1, \{2, 3, 4,\dots\}, n = 2, \{3, 4, 5, \dots\})$

$(b)$

A function is **surjective** when $f(A)$ (its image) $= B$ (target space).

The image of this clearly does not seem to equal the target space of $P(\Bbb N)$.
e.g. $P(\mathbb{N}) = \{\{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\},\dots,\{1,2,3\dots\}\}$

So, I would conclude that the function is not a surjection but is indeed an injection.

Comment: Your reasoning, in both cases, seems solid.  For the first, you can recover $n$ from its image, as it is one less than the least entry.  For the last, the set $\{1,3\}$ is not in the image (to pick a fairly random example).

Comment: As a point of interest, the cardinality is off.  No set can surjectively map onto its Power Set.  See  [Cantor's Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214807/non-existence-of-a-surjective-function-from-a-set-to-its-subsets-cantors-theor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the contraposition more useful for injectivity in this example: If $m \neq n$, then $f(m) \neq f(n)$. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $m < n$ and consider their respective images. What elements does $f(m)$ contain that $f(n)$ does not?

For surjectivity, be more concrete. What is a *specific* set in the codomain that is not witnessed by the function?