# Can the diagonal set in Cantor's Theorem of cardinality of infinite sets exist

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding the set D in the following proof (the first awnser):
[Non-existence of a Surjective Function from a Set to Its Subsets (Cantor's theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214807/non-existence-of-a-surjective-function-from-a-set-to-its-subsets-cantors-theor)

How can $\mathrm D$ = { x $\in$ A | x $\notin$ f (x) }, f being a surjective function (by assumption). Leave the type of function alone, event the fact that f is a function from A to $\mathcal P$(A) should imply that such a set is impossible to exist. How can we use it as an arugment to the proof?

**Edit**: What I mean by "impossible to exists" is that the very definition of a function says that every element of the domain must be mapped to an element in the codomain, in this case the power set of the set. **How is it possible to define a set with all the elements of the domain of a function that are not mapped to the codomain?**

Comment: It is a subset of $A$. One of the ZF axioms says that $D$ exists as a set

Comment: [The given answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/214874/6460) does not assume $f$ is surjective

Comment: "event the fact that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $P(A)$ should imply that such a set is impossible to exist." -- No, a possible function from $A$ to $P(A)$ is $a\mapsto \{a\}$, for example. For this $f$, we obtain $D=\emptyset$, and $\emptyset$  exists.

Comment: If $f:A\to\mathcal{P}(A)$ is any map, then $\{x\in A:x\notin f(x)\}$ is a perfectly well-defined set comprehension, giving a subset of $A$. In ZF this is guaranteed by the Axiom of Separation.

Comment: But, as the proof goes, "This is a good definition, since f(a) is a subset of A, and a is an element of A, we can ask whether or not a∈f(a)". Why should we ask whether or not a∈f(a)? a $\notin$ f(a) by the very definition of D.

Comment: I agree with @HagenvonEitzen that the empty set exists. But the empty set is included both in a set and its power set. How does that imply that the function is not surjective ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it is impossible for such a set to exist?

Comment: @EricWofsey, as I've said, I agree with Hagen von Eitzen that the empty set is a valid set for that definition. I fail to see how does that imply that the empty set aids in the proof of the theorem. The empty set is part of both a set and it's power set.

Comment: @EricWofsey I also think that, leaving the empty set out, and by the very definition of a funcion, every element in the domain must be mapped to an element in the codomain. Is that not right? How do we define a set that takes all the elements of the domain of a function that are not mapped to the codomain ? That is my problem.

Comment: @PeshoPeshev: Aha; you're not asking whether the element of the domain is or is not mapped to the codomain. You are asking whether the element of the domain happens to be an element **of** the element of the codomain that it is mapped to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you do not assume that $f$ is surjective. You just assume that $f$ is a function. As to how it works, let's work out a few examples...

Take $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Then $P(A) = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$.

Let us define a function $f\colon A\to P(A)$. For each of $1$, $2$, and $3$, we must specify an element of $P(A)$, that is, a subset of $A$ to be its image. For example,
$$\begin{align*}
1&\stackrel{f}{\longmapsto} \{1,3\}\\
2&\stackrel{f}{\longmapsto} \{1\}\\
3&\stackrel{f}{\longmapsto} \{1,2,3\}
\end{align*}$$
What is the set $D_f$? Well, it consists of all elements of $A$ that are not elements of their respective **image**.

1. Is $1$ in $f(1)=\{1,3\}$? Yes. So $1$ is not in $D_f$.
2. Is $2$ in $f(2)=\{1\}$? No. So $2$ **is** in $D_f$.
3. If $3$ in $f(3)=\{1,2,3\}$? Yes. So $3$ is not in $D_f$.

Thus, $D_f = \{2\}$. Note that the image of $f$ is $\{\{1\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$.

**Note well:** We are not asking whether $f(1)$ is in $P(A)$; *of course it is*. What we are asking is whether the element $1$ of the domain $A$ is **in** the element $f(1)$ of $P(A)$. You can think of the codomain as consisting of "bags of elements"; we are not asking whether $1$ is mapped to a bag, we are asking something about *what is in the bag that $1$ is mapped to.* Intuitively, we are labeling (some of) the bags, and we are asking if the bag with the label $1$ happens to have the *element* $1$ in it or not.

Now we notice that $D_f=\{2\}$ is not in the image of $f$, as expected.

Let's take a different function: $g\colon A\to P(A)$ given by
$$\begin{align*}
1&\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\{1,2,3\}\\
2&\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\{1,2,3\}\\
3&\stackrel{g}{\longmapsto}\{1,2,3\}
\end{align*}$$
Now, since for each $a\in A$ we have $a\in\{1,2,3\}=g(a)$, then no element of $A$ is in $D_g$. So $D_g=\varnothing$. Note that the image of $g$ is $\{ \{1,2,3\}\}$. So, as expected, $D_g$ is not an element of the image.

Final example. Let's take $h\colon A\to P(A)$ given by
$$\begin{align*}
1&\stackrel{h}{\longmapsto}\varnothing\\
2&\stackrel{h}{\longmapsto}\{1,3\}\\
3&\stackrel{h}{\longmapsto}\{2\}
\end{align*}$$

The image of $h$ is the set $\{ \varnothing, \{2\}, \{1,3\}\}$.

What is $D_h$? Well, $1\in D_h$, because $1\notin h(1)=\varnothing$. Also, $2\in D_h$, because $2\notin \{1,3\}=h(2)$. And $3\in D_h$, because $3\notin \{2\}=h(3)$. Thus, $D_h = \{1,2,3\}$... which is not an element of the image of $h$.

---

Now, given an arbitrary set $A$ and a function $f\colon A\to P(A)$. For each $a\in A$, $f(a)$ is a **subset** of $A$ (because it is an element of $P(A)$. Given an element $x\in A$ and a subset $S\subseteq A$, we can ask, "is $x\in S$?"$. The answer is either "yes" or "no".

So we can ask: "is $a\in f(a)$?" If the answer is "yes", then we don't put $a$ into $D_f$. If the answer is "no", then we put $a$ in $D_f$. Thus,
$$ D_f = \{a\in A\mid a\notin f(a)\}.$$
Note that it is a (potentially) different question for each element of $A$; that is, we have one subset of $A$ for each element of $a$ that we are asking the question about.

Because $D_f$ is made up of elements of $A$, $D_f$ is a subset of $A$. Thus, it is an element of $P(A)$. And now we ask whether $D_f$ is an element of the *image* of $f$; and the argument in the linked post shows that, no, for every $a\in A$, we must have $f(a)\neq D_f$. So $D_f$ is a subset of $A$ that is not in the image of $f$, and so $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thank you.